# Google bookmarks api or auth cookie generation

Tags: google-api

I want to pull https://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=xml&num=10000

There is no api to do this that I’m aware of, please let me know if one exists.

Is there any example of generating google standard auth cookies if I have the username and password?